# Change the text language of main page after login

Tags: react-native, react-i18next

I have two pages which are described in 'login.js' and 'main.js' files. When the user logs in I have to set the main page language according to the language that user has stored in his registered profile. I have checked that `_storeData` method of my `I18n.locale` is correctly set to the language user selected. But in the 'main.js' the content is not being changed. How to fix it?

### login.js

```
class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    async login() {
        this._storeData(this.props.login.getLogin, this.props.login.lPassword)
    }
    _storeData = async (user, password) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('password', password)
            I18n.locale = user.language;

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

### main.js

```
import I18n from '../../translations/i18n';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this._retrieveData()
    }
    _retrieveData = async () => {
        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
                this.props.editUser(JSON.parse(value))
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.menutext}>{I18n.t('company')}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `_retrieveData` method not from constructor but from `componentDidMount` or even in `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method if there is a possibility that locale can change through the time. Now since you call it from the constructor it happens before mount, so data which it uses can be outdated.